# Creating NGINX Server Proxy bypasses all the sub folders and assets

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to create an NGINX Proxy to another domain. The subfolder proxies perfectly. But, all the folders inside that subfolder gives a 404 error.

So, I have a domain xyz.com/website that needs to pull from example.com/website. Now the /website at xyz.com pulls the index.html from example.com and renders perfectly. But, the issue lies with the sub folder /assets/1.jpg . So, all the files under /assets folder under /website throws a 404 error

So technically xyz.com/website --> Works

But, xyz.com/website/assets/1.jpg --> Throws a 404 error

Following is the proxy_pass directive that I am using at xyz.com

```html
location  ~/website {
  proxy_pass https://example.com/;
  proxy_redirect redirect replacement;
 }
```

Can someone please help me and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hey Richard, 

Sorry. I updated the references I want xyz.com/stories/assets/1.jpg to pull assets or proxy from abc.com/stories/assets/1.jpg

Comment: That gives me a 404 for xyz.com/website too.

Comment: Hey @RichardSmith, Any idea what I am doing wrong